# Compactness in topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

1)Let $p:X\to Y$ be a closed continuous surjective function such that $p^{-1}(y)$ is compact, for each $y\in Y$. If $Y$ is compact, show that $X$ is compact.

Please help me!

Answer (score 3):

An equivalent property of compactness is the following:

If $\{C_i\}$ is a family of closed sets with the f.i.p , then

$\cap_{i} C_i\neq \emptyset$

The f.i.p property is the following:

for each $i_0, \dots , i_n$ then

$\cap_{j=0}^n C_{i_j}\neq \emptyset$

Thus we consider a family $\{C_i\}$ of closed sets with the f.i.p of X. Then

$\{f(\cap_j^n C_{i_j})\}$

is a family of closed set with the f.i.p property. But $Y$ is compact, so

$y\in \cap (f(\cap_j^nC_{i_j}))\neq \emptyset$

This means $f^{-1}(y)\cap \cap_i^n C_{i_j}\neq \emptyset$ and so the family $\{f^{-1}(y)\cap C_i\}$ of closed set in $f^{-1}(y)$ has the f.i.p property. However the fiber is compact and so

$\cap (f^{-1}(y)\cap C_i ) \neq \emptyset$

that means

$\cap C_i\neq \emptyset$

Thus $X$ is compact.

Comment: Ops you’re right, My mistake is to think that the intersection of the f(C_i)  is the image of the intersection

Comment: Actually continuity is not needed for this. Surjective and compact fibres we do need.

Comment: Better now. Nice idea to use closed characterisation of compactness because we have a closed map.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thank you very much, yes that was the idea. Also your ‘direct’ proof is interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Sketch:

Suppose that $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover of $X$.

For each $y \in Y$, the (non-empty) compact subset $p^{-1}[\{y\}]$ is covered by finitely many $\mathcal{U}(y) \subseteq \mathcal{U}$. Call the union of those finitely many covering sets $U_y \subseteq X$. Then $V_y := Y\setminus f[X\setminus U_y]$ is open in $Y$, contains $y$ and obeys $p^{-1}[V_y] \subset U_y$ (check this!)

The $V_y, y \in Y$ cover $Y$ so finitely many, say $V_{y_1},\ldots, V_{y_n}$ cover $Y$ too. Now show that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n \mathcal{U}(y_i)$ is a finite subcover for $\mathcal{U}$.